# How do I access other fields in the current row in a query from a custom VBA function?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to write some custom VBA functions to perform calculations on particular fields in a set of queries. This is what I currently have:

```
Public Function TVM(LEN_SEC As Double, ADT_CUR As Integer, TRK_PCT As Integer)
    TVM = LEN_SEC * ADT_CUR * TRK_PCT / 100#
End Function
```

This works fine, but when I create the query I have to do something like this:

```
SELECT TVM([LEN_SEC], [ADT_CUR], [TRK_PCT]) AS TRK_VMT
FROM System;
```

I would prefer to do this instead:

```
SELECT TVM()
FROM System;
```

Is there a way to access the current row being output by the query from within the VBA function? Something like this:

```
Public Function TVM(LEN_SEC As Double, ADT_CUR As Integer, TRK_PCT As Integer)
    TVM = CurrentRow.Fields("LEN_SEC") * CurrentRow.Fields("ADT_CUR") * CurrentRow.Fields("TRK_PCT") / 100#
End Function
```

These calculations are frequently used in time-sensitive custom generated reports, by several users of varying skill level and attention spans - the simpler I can make the interface for them, the better it is for our QA team.

Thanks!

Comment: Is creating a separate query (view) for this can be used? Why you need a function. Save This query and use it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what your example demonstrates.

Probably the most performance approach would be to avoid the function altogether since it only uses simple operators.

For example:

```
SELECT [LEN_SEC] * [ADT_CUR] * [TRK_PCT] / 100 as TVM
FROM System
```

Comment: I suspected there might be no way to do this, but thought I'd ask. This is not the most complicated calculation that is performed - the example was kept simple to avoid clouding the question I wanted answered. When setting up calculations where multiple, sometimes obtusely named, fields are needed, it would help to have a simple function that could be called rather than having the analysts stop to look up the formulae each time.

Comment: In that case your approach that calls the function from the stored proc with parameters passed in is really the only practical option.

Answer (score 0):

Users with limited skills would be better off creating their reports from queries than tables. Put your function with all the parameters in the query.

Select TVM from qrySystem;

Or teach them how to use the Expression Builder in the Query Designer and make sure they replace the <> with actual field names.